# Change response timeout setting (Firefox/Dojo)

Tags: ajax, firefox, servlets, dojo

We have a system that uses Firefox as a client for a Web application. The web page uses Dojo Ajax to perform a servlet POST request doing a long process. The problem is when the request exceeds 15 minutes (based on observation), the same Http request (same parameters) is performed repeatedly by the browser. The repeat request is received every 1 minute 20 seconds thereafter.

```
11:00:00 First Request
11:15:00 Repeat Request
11:16:20 Repeat Request
11:17:40 Repeat Request
11:19:00 Repeat Request
11:20:20 Repeat Request
```

My question is there a setting in the firefox config or even on the servlet part that can prevent the repeat request? This is a local system so I can control the browser settings.

Note: I know that a solution to this is to perform the long process in a thread and repeatedly poll the thread via javascript but my boss wants an easier fix if possible via settings in firefox.

Added based on comment:
The code used is the dojo toolkit dojo.xhrPost API to do the request. I am not sure if the dojo API is the one that is doing the reposting. Help from dojo expert too.

Added source based on Jeremy's comment:

```
dojo.xhrPost(
    {
        url: servlet,
        content: {
            jobName: 'DoLongProcess',
            FUNCTIONNO: dojo.byId('hdFunctionNo').value
        },
        handleAs: handleAs,
        handle: function(response) {
            cursorStyle(cursor_style_auto);
        }
    }
);
```

The version of dojo I'm using is 1.3.1 Rev: 17468. Unfortunately I cannot change the dojo to higher version since that would require a regression test on all functions.

Comment: You should fix the Javascript that sends the requests.

Comment: I used the dojo toolkit's dojo.xhrPost to do the posting. So does that mean it is the dojo that is causing the repost?

Comment: No; it's _your code_ that's causing the re-post (in all likeliness)

Comment: Without seeing your dojo.xhrPost its impossible to say - but a dojo xhrPost won't wait 15 minutes for a response for it fire's its timeout event, unless the code has been modified to do so. Can you post the code?